# @Path regex expression in RESTful server

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf

I'm writing a RESTful Java server with CXF framework.

How do I can write a @Path Regular Expression in order to obtain any URI finished in "/action" value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if its **/action/***, **/*/action**,  or **/*/action/*** you want?. Anyway here goes:

**1) /action/*** can be matched by

```
@Path("/action/{search:.*}")<br>
doStuff(@PathParam("search") List<PathSegment> list)
```

In this example, a request like **GET /action/order/2/price** will be served by the **doStuff()** method where **list** can be used to get to all the path segments in **order/2/price** captured by the regular expression.

**2) /*/action** can be matched by (WARNING untested)

```
@Path("/{search:.*}/action")
findStuff(@PathParam("search") List<PathSegment> list)
```

In this example, a request like **GET /item/2/action** will be served by the **findStuff()** method where **list** can be used to get to all the path segments in **item/2** captured by the regular expression.

**3) /*/action/*** Here I believe you are out of luck (feel free to correct me if I am wrong), for further info check this [blog](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/felipegaucho/archive/2009/09/17/url-patterns-are-more-flexible-jersey-webxml) post.

Comment: It was the second case, sorry if the question is a little bit confusing.. I'm going to try it!